# How do i build a custom "Your Account" dynamic page with wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Please can you help with a guideline on this requirement?

I have this requirement that some visitors to my site would need to login and be provided access to an Accounts page. This page will contain a list of links added by the site administrator which just lead to pages with specific contents.

Every page/link is unique to a user(Account). No two user will ever have to see one page.

Please help me. I just need a guide, you don't need to spoon feed me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you'll want to do is hide the regular dashboard for your logged in visitors.  The [Hide Dashboard plugin](http://www.im-web-gefunden.de/wordpress-plugins/iwg-hide-dashboard/) can help you with that.  After you've got logged in visitors bypassing the dashboard and going straight to their own unique profile page you'll want to start populating that profile page with the relevant dynamic content.  The [Extra User Details plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/extra-user-details/) looks like it might be a good fit for your requirements there...

Good luck!